# GCC 8 fails to compile make_shared<volatile int>()

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, volatile, make-shared

This code compiles cleanly and works with all compilers I've tried except for GCC 8 (and current GCC trunk):

```
std::make_shared<volatile int>(0)
```

I'd like to know:

1. Is GCC 8 correct to refuse this code?
2. Is there a substitute that GCC 8 will accept (with the same semantics and performance)?  I am aware of `std::atomic`, but the semantics are not the same so suggestions to use it instead of `volatile` are not what I'm looking for.

See it here: https://godbolt.org/z/rKy3od

Comment: Just to be clear: you are aware that `volatile` won't give you any sort of thread safety, and don't guarantee there won't be optimizations?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57403

Comment: `I am aware of std::atomic, but the semantics are not the same so suggestions to use it instead of volatile are not what I'm looking for.` what semantic are you looking for? I would be easier to find subtitutes for you.

Comment: That bug was on 4.8.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: Yes I am aware of what `volatile` does and does not do.

Comment: IDK your use case, but the following workaround, accepted even by GCC 4.8, might work for you (adding `volatile` is completely safe and `static_pointer_cast` works as well): `std::const_pointer_cast<volatile int>(std::make_shared<int>(0))`

Comment: @ArneVogel: Thanks for the tip.  This seems to work OK: `shared_ptr<volatile int> p = make_shared<int>(0)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the standard language this is a libstdc++ non conformance.

This is probably a mistake. `make_shared` calls `allocate_shared` with a standard allocator, `std::allocator<remove_const_t<T>>` where `T` is the type of the shared object. This allocator will only be used to get a rebinded allocator for the underlying shared object (a struct which contains the volatile int and atomic counters). So it is perfectly fine to declare this underlying object as non const non volatile.

This definition for `make_shared` will work:

```
template<class T,class...Args>
auto make_shared(Args&&...args){
    using ncvT= std::remove_cv_t<T>;
    return std::allocate_shared<T>(std::allocator<ncvT>(),std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I've filed a bug against libstdc++: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87278